# INCostSubitemXRef does not exist in database

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am getting error INCostSubitemXRef does not exist in database while release material issue in acumatica

Comment: Is feature 'Sub-items' checked in the 'Features' page?

Comment: Also make sure to put the exact error messages and traces (from tools menu) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the table truly exists in your database.  It is a standard table, so this appears to be data corruption in the form of a dropped table.  The table is INCostSubItemXRef (note the case), and the DAC is defined in PX.Objects.IN.INCostSubItemXRef.

[image]

If you find that the table exists in the database, you will need to provide more details like Acumatica version, screen/graph creating the error, and any additional information in the trace.